# Python repeat function in flask until desired result with 40 second delay

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi, sleep

I have code to close a gate with Flask on Raspberry Pi.  The gate moves slow and when I trigger the motor, it may open, close or stop depending on where it is at in the controller cycle.

I want the close() function to check if close limit switch is tripped and if not then trigger motor.  After 40 second delay I want to repeat this until the close limit switch is tripped.

Here is my close function

```
def Close():
    # Check Close Sensor
    if CloseCheck() == False:
    return 'Gate is Closed'

    trigger()
    sleep(40)
    Close()
    return null
```

Flask does not seem to be waiting for the sleep request.  Is this normal behavior? How can I re-run Close function every 40 sec until Close Sensor is triggered?

Answer (score 1):

Just loop until  `CloseCheck()` is False

```
def Close():
    # Check Close Sensor
    while CloseCheck():
        trigger() # run trigger
        sleep(40) #  sleep and repeat
    return 'Gate is Closed' # CloseCheck is False, return
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use a while loop to continually check if the gate is closed:

```
while True:
    if isGateClosed():
        break
    closeGate()
    time.sleep(40)
```

This would check every 40 seconds to see if the gate is closed, and exit the loop when that condition is true.